# LTSpice Simulations require netlist flattening on higher simulation counts?

Tags: simulation, ltspice, subcircuit

As in my previous question mentioned, i am doing bulk simulation with predefined component parameters for a given amount of runs. These are calculated and written to the file via python scripts i made myself.

When i am simulating a high number of runs, the simulation is slowed down by a process of "Expanding subcircuit ...". This only accurs over about 1000 runs and takes longer the more runs i try to simulate.
After a bit of research i found that this is to flatten the netlist of the circuit and since i am using quite a lot of opamps in the simulation this operation makes sense.

But i do not understand why this only appears on high run counts. I could imagine it being required for every simulation and just "showing up" since it got so slow because of a high run count. But then, why does it slow down at high run counts?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe lazy coding so it is re-(expanding) flattening every time it does a run?

Comment: Netlist flattening is done everytime prior to any simulation. Why it seems to occur only every X runs, I don't know, but if you think it's a bug, you might try to send it to the address that appears in `Help > About`. Maybe it's about the disk cache that needs clearing up and happens when that message appears? If so, try adding a `.save` for only the required voltages/currents (if you haven't already done so).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen `.save` is already in use, saving 2 voltages. Disk cache could be possible, but i do not know for sure since i use an samsung 1tb nvme as os drive. I will report my problem like you recommended, if i get any advice i'll comment it here.

Comment: @DKNguyen yes, it happens before every run